# Python adding arrays of different sizes - upper bound?

Tags: python

I want to add several arrays together but they have different sizes.

I think the code should look like this

```
commission = [0.55,0.03,0.025,0.025]
interest = [0.05,0.045]
premium = 10
fund = []

for i = 1 to 120
        fund[i] = premium * (1 - commission[i]) + interest[i] * fund[i-1]
```

But the issue is that this will go out of bounds.  I just want the commission[4] to extend to all 120 periods.  Same with the interest array.  Usually in the past I have used the "upperbound" command within the for loop to do this calculation.

How is it done in python?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here. You have two collections that you want to apply to _something_ in some manner. Why 120? Do you want to visit each commission or not? If you do want to visit each commission, what makes sense to you for a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this while indexing the list. All out of bounds accesses should refer to the last element by default.

You'd want to do something of the like:

```
def get_graceful_overflow(lst, idx):
    return lst[min(idx, len(lst) - 1)]
```

Now substitute calls to `commission[i]` with `get_graceful_overflow(commission, i)`. And similar for `interest`.

Comment: these solutions seem a little inelegant.  Probably it would be best to index all the arrays the same length instead.  But thanks for the comments!

Comment: @massmutual It's in a function so you can understand what it's doing. You can just as well replace `commission[i]` with `commission[min(i, 3)]`. Also, this wasn't a comment, it was an answer meant to address your question. Not sure what else you had in mind...

Comment: Should I use numpy for array calculations?  Some people mentioned this to me.

Comment: @massmutual In general, yes, but I don't really think numpy can help here because the arrays aren't the same size, and the problem is inherently iterative.

Comment: but I could make the arrays the same size

Comment: @massmutual "The problem is inherently iterative". The next value depends on the previous ones. So, it can only be done within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Which values should be used for calculations above sizes of the arrays?
You can e.g. repeat the arrays by typing

```
[0.55,0.03,0.025,0.025]*30
```

to get 120 entries.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. They want out of bounds indices to access the last value, and nothing more. This is going to cycle through elements in turn.